# Parsing different language characters and accents into valid XML

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding

I have a bunch of XML data with different language data, which has accents. Example:-

```
<text content="vídeo..." /> or <text content="vidéo..." />
```

This data is coming from MySQL - I'm then assembling the data with SimpleXML - which just refuses to even put the data in when these chars are in the content.

Tried (as someone suggested) using utf8_encode() on the data before hand, just to see if that helped.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Please add the chunk of code where you actually put data in. SimpleXML just expects the data to be encoded as UTF-8, as long as it is, this works. Are you getting an error message or are you just not confident with the output? If it's an output issue, please add how you output the XML, if it's requested by a browser or written to file etc.

Comment: ^ agree with hakre. And it's important to know in which character set you actually fetch content from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to character encoding. First you have to make sure you use encoding that matches wherever your XML is used. The encoding you use to add the data has to be the same in your XML file. If it is just for your environment you can use the encoding that works best for you but if you need it to work around the globe UTF-8 is your best bet.

If you have characters that are not known in your encoding you have to encode your strings into character references. If you do that with entity references and what `htmlentities()` does you will have to add some DTD with the entity references to your XML file because XML does only know about handful of defaults. If you need some DTDs you can download them [here](http://htmlentities.aworldproject.com/XML/Document-Type-Definitions-DTD). If you cannot use a DTD you have to use numeric references in your XML file.